# Animating DOM elements in an array

Tags: javascript, css, arrays

I have been attempting to code a Simon Says game and so far I have gotten everything working except for the animation aspect of the game.  Whenever the code iterates through the array, it animates the first time but if the same square shows up again , it wont animate the second time.

```js
let red = document.querySelector('.red');
let blue = document.querySelector('.blue');
let yellow = document.querySelector('.yellow');
let green = document.querySelector('.green');

let sounds = [red, blue, red, blue];
let i = -1;

let currentInt = setInterval(() => {
  if (i < sounds.length - 1) {
    i++;
    console.log(sounds[i]);
    sounds[i].classList.add('selected');

  }

}, 1000)
```

```css
.simonBoard {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  background-color: coral;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 30%;
  height: 400px;
}

.red {
  background-color: crimson;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: gold;
}

.blue {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.green {
  background-color: forestgreen;
}

.selected {
  animation-name: selected;
  animation-duration: 0.25s;
}

@keyframes selected {
  0% {
    border: 3px solid black;
  }
  50% {
    border: 20px solid green;
  }
  100% {
    border: 3px solid black;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="simonBoard">

  <div data-id=0 class="btn red"></div>
  <div data-id=2 class="btn yellow"></div>
  <div data-id=1 class="btn blue"></div>
  <div data-id=3 class="btn green"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an `animationend` event listener, and remove the `.selected` class (and the event listener) when the animation ends:

```js
let red = document.querySelector('.red');
let blue = document.querySelector('.blue');
let yellow = document.querySelector('.yellow');
let green = document.querySelector('.green');

let sounds = [red, blue, red, blue];
let i = -1;

let currentInt = setInterval(() => {
  if (i < sounds.length - 1) {
    i++;

    sounds[i].classList.add('selected');
    
    const eventListener = () => {
      sounds[i].classList.remove('selected');
      
      sounds[i].removeEventListener('animationend', eventListener);
    }
    
    sounds[i].addEventListener('animationend', eventListener);
  }
}, 1000)
```

```css
.simonBoard {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  background-color: coral;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 30%;
  height: 90vh;
}

.red {
  background-color: crimson;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: gold;
}

.blue {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

.green {
  background-color: forestgreen;
}

.selected {
  animation-name: selected;
  animation-duration: 0.25s;
}

/** I've change the border to shadow to prevent the element from resizing **/
@keyframes selected {
  0% {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px black;
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 20px green;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px black;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="simonBoard">
  <div data-id=0 class="btn red"></div>
  <div data-id=2 class="btn yellow"></div>
  <div data-id=1 class="btn blue"></div>
  <div data-id=3 class="btn green"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think problem here

```
    sounds[i].classList.add('selected');
```

You add class 'selected', but don't remove it, so after first iterate html become

```
<div class="simonBoard">

  <div data-id=0 class="btn red selected"></div>
  <div data-id=2 class="btn yellow selected"></div>
  <div data-id=1 class="btn blue selected"></div>
  <div data-id=3 class="btn green selected"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried removing it , but then it doesn't animate at all. I tried delaying the removal as well but it still didnt work